# Creating command history list

Tags: command-line, bash, history

Is there a way to display a list comprised of the last `n` terminal commands made by a particular user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every user has a `.bash_history` file, present in his home directory. i.e. `/home/<USERNAME>/.bash_history`. It stores all the command executed by a particular user.

You can use this file to see the command executed by a user. (You need root privilege to access file of other user.)

```
tail -n /home/<USERNAME>/.bash_history
```

Don't forget to replace `n` with actual number.

Comment: @g_p Wow, this one is reaaaaaally cool and simple, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

If your shell is `bash`, then the best way is to use the `history` command:

```
(HISTFILE=/home/user/.bash_history; history -c; history -r; history n)
```

While a bit complicated, this provides all the benefits of the `history` command (such as timestamps, if you have enabled it). The parentheses (`()`) ensure the commands are run in a subshell and don't affect the current shell.

Comment: nice trick...+1 for `HISTFILE`

Answer (score 2):

`tail -n /home/userinquestion/.bash_history` would seem the obvious answer - assuming they have bash as their shell, of course..

If there is a terminal open, it may not have written commands to the history file yet.

You will need to use su or sudo if the user is not yourself.

Comment: you are forgetting to address the "last n" ;)

Comment: Blimey Rinzwind that was quick!

Comment: guess why I removed my answer ;D

Answer (score 2):

One other option is to create a simple shell script that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail --lines=$1 /home/$(whoami)/.bash_history
```

This takes g-P's answer and makes it just a little prettier by doing more stuff automatically.

1. Run `nano history-lookup.sh` (or whatever name you want - just end it in `.sh`)
2. Paste that code in
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit.
4. Run `bash history-lookup.sh NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES`. It should spit them out nicely onto the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
history | tail -n20 > history20.txt
```

By sending the result to a text file, you can print, review, email, etc. the text file at any time.